# I am using Spark-XML to read a xml file but i am facing this error "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: python, xml, apache-spark, pyscripter

I am using windows 11 when i run this code in Python. I am trying to read an xml file which has datasetof gardening question answers,

```
*from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
def main():
gardening_raw_path = "D:\dbfs\dbdemos\product\llm\gardening\raw"
print(f"loading raw xml dataset under {gardening_raw_path}")

Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
>     .appName("module1") \
>     .getOrCreate()
shell=true

Read XML file into a DataFrame
xml_df = spark.read \
>     .format("xml") \
>     .option("rowTag", "row") \
>     .load(f"{gardening_raw_path}/Posts.xml")

Show the DataFrame schema and contents
xml_df.printSchema()
xml_df.show()

Stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()
pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()*
```

It gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Documents\module1.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Documents\module1.py", line 20, in main
    .getOrCreate()
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Ali\python\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 477, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Ali\python\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 512, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "D:\Ali\python\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 198, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "D:\Ali\python\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 432, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Ali\python\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 99, in launch_gateway
    proc = Popen(command, **popen_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Ali\python\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "D:\Ali\python\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1509, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am trying to read XML file in my Python programm using spark-XML

Comment: try to use double `\\ ` in the path string instead of single `\ `

Comment: Already tried but system gives the same error

Comment: Have you tried this? `
gardening_raw_path = r"D:/dbfs/dbdemos/product/llm/gardening/raw"

and than. ...load(f”{gardening_raw_path}/Posts.xml") `.  I would try to use allways slash or always backslash not a mixture.

Comment: It seems that the error is thrown at the creation of the spark context, Does it throw the error if you remove all of the lines after the spark context creation?

Comment: @Krezno you are right. The error is at the session creation line.
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ChatBOT").getOrCreate()

Comment: I guess then there is something broken in your spark configuration. Try maybe to print `os.environ` check what the values are of `SPARK_HOME` and other spark environment variables and see that these paths are correct